# Stanford POS tagging: get words tagged as singular nouns(NN)

Tags: java, tagging, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

```
public class Sample {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    // Initialize the tagger
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger");

    // The sample string
    String sample = "I am a good boy";
    String[] tokens = sample.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
        String tagged = tagger.tagString(tokens[i]);
         System.out.println(tagged);
    }

    // The tagged string
    //String tagged = tagger.tagTokenizedString(sample);

    // Output the result
    //System.out.println(tagged.startsWith("N"));

}
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
I_PRP 
am_VB 
a_DT 
good_JJ 
boy_NN
```

***Q:*** I need to print boy as output in the above program as it is tagged as singular nouns(NN)

Comment: There is a small amount of confusion in the question.  The question asks for NN however the question's code shows an approach for any part-of-speech beginning with N, of which there are 4.  Then, there are the pronouns beginning with P, are those important nouns?  I did the best I could with my edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Got the sol:**

MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger");

```
    // The sample string
    String s = "It implements all optional list operations and it also permits all elements, includes null.";
    String sample = s.replaceAll("\\W", " ");

    // The tagged string
    String tagged = tagger.tagTokenizedString(sample);

    // Output the result
    // System.out.println(tagged);
    String[] x = tagged.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        if (x[i].substring(x[i].lastIndexOf("_")+1).startsWith("N"))
        {
            list.add(x[i].split("_")[0]);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

list

operations

elements

null

Comment: Thank you, is this the only way to get nouns? It is strange that `MaxentTagger.tag()` cannot filter with respect to tagname before forming the `Strign` output.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to put it into an array first and then get the data which contains NN in it.

or other solution, using hash map is also make it easier to get which key you want to print.